# Pyspark DataFrame Filtering

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
|Property ID|Location|Price|Bedrooms|Bathrooms|Size|Price SQ Ft|Status|
```

When I am filtering it with bedrooms or bathrooms it is giving correct answer

```py
df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt', header=True, inferSchema=True, sep='|')
df.filter(df.Bedrooms==2).show()
```

But when I am filtering it with Property ID as  `df.filter(df.Property ID==1532201).show()` ,
I am getting an error. Is it because there is a space in betweeen Property and ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the square bracket notation to select the column:

```
df.filter(df['Property ID'] == 1532201).show()
```

Or use a raw SQL string to filter: (note the backticks)

```
df.filter('`Property ID` = 1532201').show()
```

Answer (score 2):

the *space* between *Property* and *ID* is the cause of issue.
Another approach you can follow is  as follows :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.filter(F.col('Property ID')==1532201).show()
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. I was able to do it using `df.filter(col("Property ID")==1499102).show()`.